# How can we perform ADFS authentication in our Dot net application

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

Can anyone tell me how can we use SSO/ADFS authentication in dot net app.

Comment: post some code. your question will seriously get downvoted if you dont post code.  use this to learn how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You add the WS-Fed OpenID NuGet package.

Ideally, you would use OpenID Connect but you need ADFS on Server 2016 for that.

Refer: [Use the OWIN Security Components in ASP.NET to Implement Web Sign On with ADFS](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/29/use-the-owin-security-components-in-asp-net-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs/).